# How to know owner application of a method call inside Dalvik VM (Portable Interpreter)

Tags: methods, virtual-machine, trace, dalvik

I am trying to get the corresponding application/process id/name from within the method `GOTO_InovkeMethod` of android/dalvik/vm/mterp/c/gotoTragets.cpp.

I have used `self->systemTid` as the process id, but using this miss many method calls originally done by the application.

Answer (score 0):

The process ID can be obtained from `getpid()`.

A single VM runs within a single process, so the process ID will always be the same within a given instance.